# Testcafe: One report for multiple runners

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

In my Testcafe project I have multiple runners and I would like to have one reporter for all runners instead of logging the failed tests. Any suggestions?

Code below:

```
const testCafe = createTestCafe("localhost", 1337, 1338);
import util from "util";

(async () => {
  try {
    const runner1 = testCafe
      .createRunner()
      .src("testcafe/fixtures/first-fixture.js")
      .reporter([{ name: "spec", output: "report1.txt" }])
      .browsers("chrome");

    const runner2 = testCafe
      .createRunner()
      .src("testcafe/fixtures/second-fixture.js")
      .reporter([{ name: "spec", output: "report2.txt" }])
      .browsers("chrome");

    await Promise.all([runner1, runner2].map(runner => runner.run())).then(
      result => {
        console.log(`Failed tests: ${result[0] + result[1]}`);
      }
    );
  } catch (error) {
    await console.error(util.inspect(error));
  } finally {
    await testCafe.close();
  }
})();
```

Comment: What do you plan to do with the test results? Are you going to run these tests using a CI service? It is impossible to use a single reporter for multiple runners, but you can aggregate test results using a CI.

Comment: I have 142 tests at the moment which takes around 42 minutes to run sequential in a docker contianer on jenkins. The idea is to run many of these in parallel in a docker container on jenkins to reduce the testing time. At the moment jenkins uses the report.xml, generated by the sequential testing but when running in parallel many of these are generated for each runner, so I would like to have one summarised report that Jenkins can use.

Comment: Did you consider using the runner.concurrency() method? Another option is to use the junit reporter and aggregate test results in the junit publisher ([https://plugins.jenkins.io/junit/](https://plugins.jenkins.io/junit/)), e.g. junit 'report*.xml'.

Comment: Thank you for your great answer. I will give junit i shot :-)

Comment: You can also use the Testcafe Jenkins plugin(https://plugins.jenkins.io/testcafe/) with junit publisher